# Running .NET Core console app as a service, or redo?

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-server

We have orders that come in from a third party encoded UTF-16 LE. Our ERP can only read UTF-8 encoding. So I've created the .NET Core console app that watches the directories the orders arrive in and writes them to where the ERP grabs the files. How do I let this run on our Windows Server 2016? Should I scrap it and write it as a Windows Service?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class RewriteUsingUTF8
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string ordrstkPath = @"\\Rep-app\sftp_root\supplypro\ordrstk";
        string conrstkPath = @"\\Rep-app\sftp_root\supplypro\Conrstk";
        Watch(ordrstkPath);
        Watch(conrstkPath);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Watch(string path)
    {
        //initialize
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        //assign parameter path
        watcher.Path = path;

        //create event
        watcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.Attributes;

        //only look for csv
        watcher.Filter = "*.csv";

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    // method when event is triggered (file is created)
    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)

    {

        ReadWriteStream(e.FullPath, e.Name);

    }

    private static void ReadWriteStream(string path, string fileName)
    {

        FileStream originalFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        //destination path by replacing SFTP user directory
        string destinationPath = path.Replace(@"\supplypro\", @"\ftpuser\");

        FileStream destinationFileStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(originalFileStream);

        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(destinationFileStream);

        string currentLine;

        try
        {
            currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
            while (currentLine != null)
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(currentLine);
                currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }

            //archive path
            string archivePath = path.Replace(fileName, @"\archive\" + fileName);

            //move to archive path
            File.Move(path, archivePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //error path
            string errorPath = path.Replace(fileName, @"\error\" + fileName);

            //move to error path
            File.Move(path, errorPath);

            //need to write code for error to write to event viewer
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //dispose resources
            streamReader.Close();
            streamWriter.Close();
            originalFileStream.Close();
            destinationFileStream.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

I have looked at a few similar posts, but am unsure what direction I should take. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could rewrite it as a service-- that has certain advantages-- but the least amount of work would be to leave it as a console app and just schedule it to run occasionally using [Windows task scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like we're working in very similar environments. We started off using console apps for our ERP integrations. Their main drawbacks are that they run on a user's desktop, so you have to RDP in as that user to manage them, and they don't restart automatically if the server reboots. I've been converting them all to Windows services. .NET Core makes it fairly easy.

Tim Corey has an excellent video about how to write [Windows services in .NET Core 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzrTiz_NRKA). He talks about deleting and recreating the service when deploying a new version, but I haven't found that to be necessary. Just RDP in, stop the service so none of the files are in use, deploy, and start it again. It's not as simple as redeploying a .NET Core web app, which manages all the stopping and restarting for you, but it's not too bad.

A crucial thing to know is that exceptions absolutely must not propagate out of `Worker.ExecuteAsync`. They will not be handled anywhere, and Windows will show your service as running when it's not. Whatever you do in `ExecuteAsync`, do it in a loop that catches all exceptions and keeps running.

File watchers are deceptively complicated. Make sure you're listening for error events. For example, if you're watching a network share and it becomes unavailable, the `FileSystemWatcher` will emit an error and will *not* resume working when the share comes back online. I haven't figured out the best way to handle errors, though. I think making it reliable requires replacing the `FileSystemWatcher` after any error.

Comment: Thank you! I'll dive into the worker service and look into adding error event listening into my `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: Hello, I've rewritten this using .NET core worker service. However, I am getting a 1053 error when I start the service. Have you run into this issue before? I will most likely make a new post on SO, as I have added the windows hosting package and included UseWindowsService() in my HostBuilder.

Comment: [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810904/1053-windows-service-error-using-net-core-3-1-worker-service)