# 1053 Windows Service Error using .NET Core 3.1 Worker Service

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've create a Worker Service that works as intended on both debug and release in Visual Studio 2019. The service watches for .csv to be created, and rewrites it with proper encoding (UTF-8) to another directory. When I've published it, and a Windows Service is created, on starting the Windows Service I am receiving `Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`. From what I understand, my `OnStart` is not returning quick enough. But I am unsure of how to debug.

**Program class**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using System;

namespace SupplyProUTF8service
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(@"\\REP-APP\temp\workerservice\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Application Started.");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Log.Fatal(e, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseWindowsService().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services)
                => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); }).UseSerilog();
    }
}
```

**New Worker Class**
**Still get 1053 error**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SupplyProUTF8service
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {

        private readonly string ordrstkPath;
        private readonly string conrstkPath;
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            ordrstkPath = @"\\Rep-app\sftp_root\supplypro\ordrstk";
            conrstkPath = @"\\Rep-app\sftp_root\supplypro\Conrstk";
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            _logger.LogInformation("SupplyProRewrite Service started");
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }


        private FileSystemWatcher Watch(string path)
        {
            //initialize
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
            {

                //assign paramater path
                Path = path,

                //don't watch subdirectories
                IncludeSubdirectories = false
            };

            //file created event
            watcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;

            //filters
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.Attributes;

            //only look for csv
            watcher.Filter = "*.csv";

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            return watcher;
        }
        private void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{FullPath} has been created", e.FullPath);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            while (!IsFileLocked(e.FullPath))
            {
                ReadWriteStream(e.FullPath, e.Name);
                break;
            }
        }

        private static bool IsFileLocked(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using FileStream originalFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                originalFileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void ReadWriteStream(string path, string fileName)
        {

            string originalPath = path;
            //destination path by replacing SFTP user directory
            string destinationPath = path.Replace(@"\supplypro\", @"\ftpuser\");

            string currentLine;

            using FileStream originalFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using FileStream destinationFileStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(originalFileStream);
            using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(destinationFileStream);
            try
            {
                currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
                while (currentLine != null)
                {

                    streamWriter.WriteLine(currentLine);
                    currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();

                }

                streamReader.Close();
                streamWriter.Close();

                //archive path
                string archivePath = path.Replace(fileName, @"archive\" + fileName);

                //move to archive path
                while (!IsFileLocked(originalPath))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Move(originalPath, archivePath, true);
                        _logger.LogInformation("{FileName} moved to archive", fileName);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError("Unable to move {fileName} to archive", fileName, e);
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //error path
                string errorPath = path.Replace(fileName, @"error\" + fileName);

                //move to error path
                while (!IsFileLocked(originalPath))
                {
                    File.Move(path, errorPath);
                    _logger.LogError("{FullPath} file was moved to error", originalPath, e);
                    break;
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                destinationFileStream.Close();
                originalFileStream.Close();

            }
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using (Watch(ordrstkPath))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("ordrstk being watched");
                await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);
            }

            using(Watch(conrstkPath))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("conrstk being watched");
                await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using this pattern wrong. This isn't how `BackgroundService` is supposed to work. Instead, implement `IHostedService` instead of `BackgroundService` and override `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`

Comment: Should you be using *ExecuteAsync* instead of *StartAsync*? I do not have extensive Worker Service experience yet, but a program I have that is somewhat similar, as in it is always watching, has all the functionality on *ExecuteAsync*. I think that *StartAsync* code is not finishing and that's why it gives you the response it does?

Comment: @AndyTotally incorrect. The template for a Worker Service project (which is how you write Windows services with .NET Core) generates a class called `Worker` that extends `BackgroundService` with a stub for implementing `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: @Andy I conditionally retract my earlier comment. What I described is how MS intends it to be done now. But there's this [insidious bug](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2831), and the workaround involves doing it the old way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't do this in the first place. My apologies to those who took their time to look at this. I ended up running the application in Powershell with `.\WorkerService.exe`. This threw the error that I was missing the runtime for ASP.net Core. I had previously installed the runtimes for .NET core and recently the 5.0. This worker service must need the specific ASP.Net Core with hosting runtime: [Download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.10-windows-hosting-bundle-installer). Service starts without issue now.

Answer (score 4):

The same issue happened in the Dot Net core 6 service project(Default Project template from visual studio 2022) on the windows 11 machine.
Use **UseWindowsService()** after the host declartion.

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
}).UseWindowsService()
.Build();await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: That was my case 2. For ASP.NET Core 7 app A. reference this package: "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="7.0.0" B. Add this to your program.cs: builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

Comment: Thank you both. With this problem there is no error at all in the Windows logs.

Answer (score 1):

Since `FileSystemWatcher` isn't async in the sense of the `async` keyword, but is `IDisposable`, your `ExecuteAsync` might look like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
{
    using (/* method that sets up and returns your watcher */)
    {
        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancel);
    }
}
```

Not shown here, but you'll probably want to catch the `TaskCanceledException` thrown by `Task.Delay` when the service is shut down.

Comment: OK, so my `Watch` method should be called in `ExecuteAsync`. Now my current `Watch` method does not return a watcher, it only triggers the created event which I handle. Should I be going about this a different way?

Comment: @RyanFreemark I suggested writing a method that returns the watcher as a convenience to make the code more readable. My example code is just an easy way to ensure the watcher is properly cleaned up when the service is stopped.

Comment: I've moved my Watch method into the `ExecuteAsync` but I still am receiving the 1053 error upon clean release publish and new service. Is there a way I can debug this? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed **error 1053** using `UseWindowsService()` thanks for the recommendation.

I have seen that in `NET core 3` it was not like that.

```
using WindowsService;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    }).UseWindowsService ()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```